# How to navigate on a TabBar on .NET MAUI/Blazor hybrid?

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

So I am just experimenting with the .NET MAUI/Blazor Hybrid.

I have followed a .NET MAUI guide to setup my TabBar and that results in it looking like this:

[image]

However I need to link each tab to a razor page so ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Home}" for example doesn't work.

Does any body know how I link each tab to a razor page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of each of those data templates you will want to have a template that has a `BlazorWebView` pointing to the page you want to show. Written out in one file. that would look something like this, of course you can put each template in a different file:

```xml
<Application.MainPage>
    <Shell>
        <TabBar>
            <Tab Title="Home">
                <ShellContent Title="Home">
                    <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPage>
                                <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                                    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                                        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Index}" />
                                    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                                </BlazorWebView>
                            </ContentPage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
                </ShellContent>
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Log">
                <ShellContent Title="Log">
                    <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPage>
                                <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                                    <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                                        <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Counter}" />
                                    </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                                </BlazorWebView>
                            </ContentPage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
                </ShellContent>
            </Tab>
        </TabBar>
    </Shell>
</Application.MainPage>
```

Note:

1. I added a `xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Pages"` namespace declaration
2. I point each `BlazorWebView` to one of the (Blazor) pages in the namespace about

Find the full working sample here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiBlazorPlatformTabs

Comment: While this works, when I try to do this, the MainLayout does not get used.

Comment: I think that's the whole point. Because part of the main layout would be the menu, right? And that would be a bit weird to have that in there again also

Comment: In addition to learning how all this works, I am coming at this from using this in the Flyout where I want to have the MainLayout working.  Really any layout, as I am not able to specific other layouts when I navigate to the Blazor page like this.

Comment: I think I see where I am missing the boat.  I am wanting to navigate to a Blazor page that is in an existing BlazorWebView, not fire up a new BlazorWebView.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis: in this scenario, how can I have a link on one page to go to another page (Say from Index to Counter page in your example) ?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis , it is not just layout, we lost boostrap css and js as well. It means we cannot utilize bootstrap component in razor pages. Therefore we need layout one way or another...

Comment: @EmadGabriel Have you found a way to navigate to another blazor page that is in BlazorWebView?

Comment: @ACThompson Could you let me know how you were able to navigate between razor pages that are in 2 tabs with their own BlazorWebView?

Comment: @john This should be it's own question.  We abandoned that structure to go with one blazorwebview in the app with a lot of razor pages.  Built our own tab bar at the bottom using Blazor.  I would create a service class using dependency injection to share that class between the two controls.  That class has to have a reference to the application to push/pop xaml pages and accept parameters that the razor page with route "/" listens to so it can navigate to the appropriate razor page.

Comment: @ACThompson That's a great piece of advice. By any chance do you have a sample github repository to see the navigation and the bottom nav bar in razor, please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a folder name Pages and put all pages in it,
2. Add `xmlns:Page="clr-namespace:Market.Pages"` where `Market` is your
   project name,
3. In tab add `<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Page:DetailsPage}"/>` where `DetailsPage` here is your navigation page (see [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1T3N.png))