# .NET MAUI: How to have Blazor page use the layout when navigating from the Shell

Tags: .net-maui, maui-blazor

I am able to navigate to a Blazor page from the shell thanks to [How to navigate on a TabBar on .NET MAUI/Blazor hybrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258228/how-to-navigate-on-a-tabbar-on-net-maui-blazor-hybrid)

However the MainLayout is not used even if I specify it in the Blazor page.

[GitHub source replicating the problem] (https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiBlazorPlatformTabs)

*edit
Goal was to navigate to a page in an existing BlazorWebView from the AppShell Flyout.  This method is creating a new "website" with the one page.

Comment: Sorry,I'm not sure what you mean by words `Goal was to navigate to a page in an existing BlazorWebView from the AppShell Flyout. This method is creating a new "website" with the one page.`  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish the functionality of Shell navigation and Shell Flyout but use Blazor pages instead of XAML.  I am trying to see if I could integrate Blazor with AppShell.  I want to be able to swipe to reveal the Flyout, tap a selection to a Blazor page, user navigates through Blazor pages and then allow the user to be able to Back up through the page stack.

Comment: Any clue on this? Having same problem as well.

Comment: No.  We are going the route of every Blazor page will have a backing XAML page.  Which means every Blazor page will stand on it's own for its layout.