# Razor page navigation inside Maui Blazor

Tags: .net, navigation, blazor, maui

I am using this template from Versluis to build an application https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiBlazorPlatformTabs/tree/main/MauiBlazorPlatformTabs

It has 2 Tabs, both with razor pages.

Inside the index.razor i have this:

```
@page "/"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<button @onclick="Navigate">Click</button>


@code{
    
    private void Navigate()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Test");
    }
}
```

Then i create a third page with the following content:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@page "/Test"

<h3>Test</h3>

<button @onclick="GoBack">Click</button>

@code {
    private void GoBack()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Well, when i come into the app and click the button, it goes to the Test page as intended, but when i change the tab, and come back to the index, the button does not work anymore.

Why?

Comment: A similar case from SO [.NET MAUI: How to have Blazor page use the layout when navigating from the Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575530/net-maui-how-to-have-blazor-page-use-the-layout-when-navigating-from-the-shell).

Comment: @Dakxin Is this issue resolved? Could you share how you were able to fix this?